# Getting 404 cms_wysiwyg directive image URL

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms, nginx, wysiwyg, tinymce

[image: Broken images]

I noticed in the Magento CMS editor TinyMCE, the image thumbnails are set as the following format after a base64 encode of the shortcode `{{media url="wysiwyg/foobar.gif"}}`

`index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l...`

This is happening on nginx and not on apache. Perhaps it's an environmental issue however my question aims to solve this on the Magento layer.

[image: 404]

My question is, how does Magento decode this `___directive...` URL? and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for building these types of links appears to be done in getImageHtmlDeclaration function in the file /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php

```
$html = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/cms_wysiwyg/directive', array('___directive' => $directive));
```

The code for displaying these images is in the file /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php

```
public function directiveAction
```

Here is loads the parameter, urlDecodes it using the core helper, uses the email template to produce the real url to the image.

I would suggest to look into file /lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php as this has the function filter which appears to be where the final url change happens. This will take the image in format:

```
{{skin url='images/home_main_callout.jpg'}}
```

And convert to a real url format.